# Serial/RS-232 Button

Tags: usb, remote-control, rs-232

I have searched for a single button (sort of like an arcade button) that connects via RS232 and I have not found one.  Anyone know of such a device?  I'm sure I could build one but I am looking for a commercially available device.

I found a USB button but the application I am using asks for a COM Port number.  Will the USB button work?

Comment: "the application I am using asks for a COM Port number" implies that you have a specific unstated requirement for what the button would do.  Given that, the question is unanswerable until you clarify what the software expects.  The situation would be far simpler if you were creating the software and could make it work in the easiest way possible, for example looking at the modem status lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [pushbutton](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017KPM0S2). There are many like it, but this one is yours.

And this is how you [connect it to your serial port](http://reversemidastouch.blogspot.com/2012/06/create-simple-rs232-pushbutton-switch.html).

Usually these kinds of things require a little modification, unless such a part is sold by the very people who made the software you're using.

The USB solution may work just as well, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've seen that article and I guess there is no commercially available pushbutton(s) that just connect via RS-232.  Fashioning one seems to be the only way.  Thanks again.

Comment: This may or may not be a solution - for custom software it would be, but the poster seems to need to satisfy an existing piece of software with unknown expectations.

Comment: You're right, it isn't a specific solution; the user will have to determine which pins need to be soldered to the pushbutton. It is the most accurate solution I was able to determine.